# How to create circles using CSV height, weight, radius and colors in d3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have CSV data with height, weight, radius and colors.

I'm trying to make circles using this data but just getting nothing (a white window)

This is the code:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>companies</title>
    <style>
    svg {
        background-color: gray;
        height: 400px;
        width: 800px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
           d3.csv("company.csv", function (the_data) {build_viz(the_data);});

        function build_viz(the_data) {
                    d3.select("svg")
                        .selectAll("circles")
                        .data(the_data)
                        .enter()
                        .append('circle')
                        .attr('cx', function (d) { return d.X; })
                        .attr('cy', function (d) { return d.Y; })
                        .attr('r', function (d) { return d.radius; })
                       .style("background-color", function (d) { return d.color; });
    }

    </script>
</body>
```

Do you know what is missing here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your company.csv like

X,Y,radius

100,20,10

150,80,10

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>companies</title>
    <style>
        .svg {
            background-color: gray;
            height: 400px;
            width: 800px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <svg class='svg'></svg>
    <script>


        d3.csv('./company.csv', function (the_data) {
            console.log("X", the_data.X)
            console.log("radius", the_data.radius)
            build_viz(the_data);
        });

        function build_viz(the_data) {

            d3.select('.svg')
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", the_data.X)
                .attr("cy", the_data.Y)
                .attr("r", the_data.radius)
                .attr('fill', 'red')
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I've corrected the code (only without the log.console) and it works with live server.  now I need to add labels with mouseover with on() function. see in the code above. Do you know what to change here?

Comment: If you changed the question, please ask it under a new post because other people can benefit from your first question. If my answer was enough for the first question, do not forget to confirm my answer for other users.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `svg` element in the page's body.

As a consequence, `d3.select("svg")` returns an empty selection, so the circles are not appended to anything.

Fix by adding the following inside `<body>`, *before* the script:

```
<svg width="800px" height="400px"></svg>
```